# Media player is not playing any audio when application is in LockTask (KIOSK Mode)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I make my device as admin after installation.

Media player is not playing any audio when application is in LockTask (KIOSK Mode)

I have written a handle to enable/disable KIOSK MODE

I am trying to play a simple audio file from res/raw. Volume of the device is set to high.

```
 mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.panic_ring)
        mediaPlayer?.start()
        mediaPlayer?.isLooping = true
```

But still I cannot hear anything from device

If I disable KIOSK mode by calling `enableKioskMode(false)` then I can hear sound just fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you have not set
   User Restriction in DevicePolicyManager
   i.e UserManager.DISALLOW_ADJUST_VOLUME
2. Add code to put your phone on RINGER mode with full volume

```
    private fun setDeviceOnRingerMode(applicationContext: Context) {
        val am: AudioManager? =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager?
        am?.ringerMode = AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL
        Settings.System.putInt(
            applicationContext.contentResolver,
            android.provider.Settings.System.NOTIFICATION_SOUND,
            1
        )
    }
```